# Setting SSL for a few pages

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, ssl

At the moment, everything on my site redirects to https. This is great. I would love to use ssl. But right now, not everything is using SSL so I want to slowly transfer everything over. So I would like for a couple of pages (register.html, register.php, textlimit.html, textlimit.php).
This would be much appreciated.

My .htaccess is currently

```
SetEnv TZ America/Los_Angeles

# Prevent viewing of htaccess file.
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

# Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes

# Compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add just below `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:register\.html|register\.php|textlimit\.html|textlimit\.php)$
```

Or in an easier format if you want to add more later:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:register\.html|register\.php)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:textlimit\.html|textlimit\.php)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/other\.html$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/other2\.html$
```